# How real-time is an arduino (react to sensor)?

Tags: serial, sensors

New to arduino here, sorry for asking what may be a trivial question.

I need to simulate an industrial machine at home. It operates in a cyclic motion, creating an event for every rotation / cycle. Imagine a turntable or wheel with a marker in one place.

What I would like is:

- Have a physical wheel which I turn one rotation every 300 msec. This is the length in time of a cycle.
- Read a marker on this wheel using a sensor, such as Sick or Omron. I have this already. Sensor can be PNP or NPN, providing a closed or open connection. I can go via an optocoupler if needed.
- Once a signal is seen, the arduino should send a (sequential) string using RS232 to a PC. Approximately 90 characters.  It is not needed to wait for response.

My question is: would be time for arduino to do this be relatively constant - ie, send out the data at approximately same point in the cycle. Example: signal read at "12" on the clock, data sent around "5".

If possible, what sort of Arduino would I be looking at ?

Or do I need something more real-time for such project, like a PLC ?

Comment: You are asking for two different things: latency of your system and the jitter

Comment: You’re talking about responding to a an approximately 3.33Hz signal that you can monitor with a simple edge-triggered interrupt using a microcontroller running at almost six _million_ times that frequency. You should be perfectly fine, even factoring in the few hundred instructions to send the serial data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> one rotation every 300 msec.

300 ms is a *very long time* for an Arduino, even for an AVR-based
one, like an Uno.

I did a little experiment. I generated (with an Arduino...) a periodic
signal consisting of a 96 µs-wide negative pulse repeating every
300 ms. I sent that signal to an Arduino Uno running the following
code:

```cpp
const uint8_t sensor_pin = 3;

// 90-byte message.
const char message[] = "Korem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur "
        "adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\r\n";

void setup() {
    pinMode(sensor_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (digitalRead(sensor_pin) == LOW) {
        Serial.write(message);

        // Wait until the signal rises again.
        while (digitalRead(sensor_pin) == LOW)
            continue;
    }
}
```

This is not the nicest way to do edge detection, but for this simple
test it will do. You may notice that I am not using interrupts for
capturing the pulse: 96 µs is long enough to be captured with this
simple `digitalRead()`. I then captured the input and output signals
with a dual-channel pocket oscilloscope. Here is a screen capture:

[image: Oscilloscope screen capture]

The cyan trace at the top is the received pulse. The yellow trace below
is the output of the serial port. The negative pulse on this trace that
is almost coincident with the received pulse is the start bit. Then the
signal rises to transmit the first data bit, which is a 1 (that's
why I chose “K” rather than “L” as the first letter).

What you can see in this capture is that the latency of the Arduino is
tiny at this scale: a small fraction of the duration of the start bit.
What you cannot see is the jitter, which is quite large in *relative*
terms, but still small compared to the time scales relevant to you. In
short, the delay between the falling edge on the input and the falling
edge of the serial port start bit fluctuates roughly between 10 and
20 µs. Yes, those are **micro**seconds. This delay is roughly
20,000 times shorter than the rotation period. If the signal is read at
“12” on the clock, the start bit fires at 12 hours with
0 minutes and 2 seconds.

Note that, on the other hand, the time needed to send the message at
9600 b/s is 93.6 ms, a significant fraction of the rotation
period. And I didn't look at the behavior of the USB-to-serial converter
chip, which is another can of worms...

Comment: There's no reason why the serial port speed can't be increased. I'm always using 115200 as baud rate, and never had any problems.

Comment: @PMF: The OP has a very good reason to not increase the serial port speed: he wants to simulate an industrial device that speaks at 9600 b/s.

Comment: Note that a 90 char message will probably exceed the output buffer size of the (chip being used on the) Arduino. There's obviously ways around this (send a few bytes, delay, send a few more...) but there's both a risk of determinate overrun here (the last message hasn't yet been written when the wheel comes round to its trigger point) and an indeterminate overrun (interrupts are still being serviced when the wheel comes round). The first case will be easy enough to recognise but the second less so... and might be enough to cause problems if this is being used for e.g. ignition timing.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I see nothing in the question that specifies the speed of the actual device he wants to simulate. But if the message was, in fact, to long to be transmitted within a time slot, that would be the same for the real system as well.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: The output buffer of the chip in question is one byte deep. Two bytes if you count the shift register holding the remaining bits of the byte being transmitted. And yet, the code I posted has no issues reliably sending the whole message: `Serial.write()` is smarter than you think. There is no risk of overrun as long as the input pulses are spaced more than 93.6 ms apart, and they only come every 300 ms.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thank you kindly, but HardwareSerial.h demonstrates precisely how smart it is: either 16 or 64 bytes depending on the type of chip/board. I assure you that it *IS* possible to overrun that.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: My point is, even with this 64-byte internal buffer, `Serial.write()` reliably sends a 90-byte string if asked to.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Not in all cases in my experience. However /my/ point is that if the ISR is still clearing the buffer at the time that the next revolution pulse arrives it is likely to result in indeterminate jitter... unless of course it's attached to a higher-priority interrupt, which I suspect is unlikely (and which is definitely not the case in your posted example).

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: Re “_Not in all cases in my experience_”: If `Serial.write()` does not send reliably 90 bytes when asked to, you have a bug in your code. Probably one that is corrupting memory. Re “_if the ISR is still clearing the buffer.._”: In this case, a new message is due while the previous one has not been sent completely. Of course there will be extra jitter! There is no way around this. Fortunately for the OP, the messages take 93.6 ms to send and are sent every 300 ms.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I disagree. However I think I was using Serial.print() etc. when I discovered this rather than Serial.write() (and that I can't remember the precise symtoms), and I would caution that even in the Serial.write() case if it can't fit the data into the available buffer then it's likely to pause the main loop (with an effect on any hardcoded delay) rather than magically allocating more storage space. However your point about a 90-byte message occupying roughly 90 mSec at 9600 BPS is of course a good one.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: You are right about the pause. In this instance, `Serial.write()` takes 26 ms to complete. I did not mention that in the answer because I believe the OP is not going to be concerned about that, as his main concern was whether there would be a latency in the hundreds of milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: any Arduino is probably sufficient for your purpose when done properly.

I'll assume a proper HIGH/LOW binary signal from the sensor, HIGH when it "sees" the marker, LOW when it doesn't.

What could go wrong?

1. You use `digitalRead()` to get the state of the digital input. Depending on the pulse width, you might not catch the high state. Use interrupts instead.
2. Sending the data over Serial port takes longer than a turn of the machine. 90 bytes at 9600 bit/s needs (90 bytes * 10 bits/byte / (9600 kbit/s) = 93ms. In 300ms, there's enough time to send the 90 bytes. And 9600 bit/s is quite slow: you can probably use 115200 bit/s on short or shielded wires.
3. "Approximately 90 characters": calculate everything for the maximum data that will eventually be sent
4. Getting the data on Arduino side takes too long. You didn't give details on where those 90 bytes come from. Asking 90 devices to each give you a byte of data might not be possible in 300ms.
5. Receiving the data on the PC side (or whatever) might be delayed, because it is buffered. Especially USB to Serial adapters have no guaranteed timing. Doing the math for USB devices is hard.
6. Threading on the PC side: due to the OS Thread scheduling, the application that shall receive the data might not get CPU time for several milliseconds, 16ms (1/64s) is quite common. Doing the math is impossible (try running 8 real time threads that do something else and your PC is basically frozen)
7. Processing on the PC side: unknown
8. Displaying: after processing until a signal is displayed on the screen, that may take another 16 ms (at 60 Hz refresh rate).

> would be time for Arduino to do this be relatively constant

Relatively: yes. It certainly depends on the implementation (the Arduino C++ code).

If the data to send is hard coded 90 characters, I would expect the complete signal has been sent at before the 4 o'clock mark (94ms /300ms * 12 hours ~ 3 hours) . I see the problem more on the receiving side (see points 5., 6., 7. and 8.).

> what sort of Arduino would I be looking at ?

I don't know all of them, but an Uno will certainly work. If you only have that one digital input, even smaller ones are probably ok. Just start with an Uno or what you have available and see how it goes.

> do I need something more real-time for such project, like a PLC?

I don't see a need for a PLC in your project.

Comment: Your answer is also useful, but I had to accept the other once for providing exact measurements.  As this would just be a *simulation* the 90 characters would be just fixed text and an increasing counter, so no delay getting input from anywhere. The receiving end is well capable of handling the input.  Unfortunately switching to 115k is not possible due to the actual machine being simulated.

Comment: @MyICQ: accepting the other answer is ok. I am not overly happy with the digitalRead() decision of that answer - probably because I had too many issues with digitalRead() not working reliably enough in my projects. Anyway, if the suggested code is roughly what you need, that's a fine answer.

Comment: What would be the alternative to `digitalRead()` ? I am new to Arduino, and somehow the event of sending serial string should be triggered ?

Comment: @MyICQ: note that I accidentally calculated with kbits/s instead of bit/s, so I was off by a factor of 1000. OMG! See the new calculation. The whole data is sent at around the 3 o'clock mark

Comment: @MyICQ: use digitalRead() as suggested by Edgar. Later you can try https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/

Comment: 1. I am not a huge fan of `digitalRead()` either, but it has the benefit of simplicity, and it is newbie-friendly. If the stuff was really time-critical, I would use interrupts. With care, because printing to Serial from interrupt context has its issues. 2. 90 bytes at 9600/8N1 should take 93.75 ms (do not forget the start and stop bits). At the Arduino-rounded “9600 bps” speed it takes 93.6 ms.